# Error while detecting cars on video TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Tags: trackback

I am new to Python, working on vehicles detection, and I am getting this error.

I do not know why I am getting this error and what the solution is to solve the problem.

I am getting an error on the following line.

I have tried the solution, and I found but have not solved the problem:

```
frame = cv2.resize(frame,(frameWidth/2, frameHeight/2)) 
frameHeight, frameWidth, fdepth = frame.shape
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
frame = cv2.resize(frame,(int(frameWidth/2), int(frameHeight/2))) 
frameHeight, frameWidth, fdepth = frame.shape
```

When you divide odd numbers by 2 you end up creating a floating point value.